# How to set thickness of rounded frame in listings?

Tags: listings

I'm using `listings` package for source code listings in my master's thesis.

How to set frame thickness for `lstlisting` environement when `frameround` is set to `tttt`? When `frameround` is other than `nnnn`, `framerule` command doesn't work...

Here is my `\lstset` command:

```
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{green!5},
    rulecolor=\color{green!40!black},
    frameround=tttt,
    %framerule=1.5pt,  % frame thickness, not compatible with frameround=tttt
    basewidth=0.50em,
    frame=single,
}
```

Comment: The `listings` packages uses `\thinlines` and `\thicklines` and  `\linethickness` and other commands to change the rule width if `frameround=tttt` and not `framerule=...` -- it's stated in the manual.

Comment: yes, I read the manual, but how to controll the thickness of `\thicklines` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use `tcolorbox` and its frame management features. The `tcblistings` environment uses `listings` in the background then.

The individual options can be set either in `\tcbset{...}` or directly as an argument to `tcblistings` or in a `\newtcblisting` environment definition. (I've shown the direct and the `\newtcblisting` way, but the screenshot shows only the output of the first approach)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% Defining a special listing box with green background a dark green border color. 
\newtcblisting{mygreencode}[1]{%
  boxsep=1pt,
  boxrule=2pt,
  arc=3mm, 
  auto outer arc,
  colframe=green!40!
  black,colback=green!5,
  listing options={language=C},
  listing only,
  #1
}



\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{boxsep=1pt,boxrule=2pt,arc=3mm, auto outer arc,colframe=green!40!black,colback=green!5,listing options={language=C},listing only}
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main( int argc, char **argv )
  {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return (0);
  }
\end{tcblisting}

    \begin{mygreencode}{}
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main( int argc, char **argv )
  {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return (0);
  }
\end{mygreencode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings} 
\lstnewenvironment{Ccode}{%
  \thicklines
  \lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{green!5},
    rulecolor=\color{green!40!black},
    frameround=tttt,
    frame=single,
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    basewidth=0.50em,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  }}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{Ccode}
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
            return (0);
}
\end{Ccode}

\end{document}
```

[image]